# java spring context:property-placeholder manually loading

Tags: java, spring, properties, loading

Spring java- quartz schedular application

**I want to load .property file dynamically passed throw program parameter instead of context:property-placeholder in spring context, how can i achieve this task, any help appreciated...**

I am manually loading and refreshing spring context from main java file as illustrate by following code.

```
SpringUtil_1.loadSpringConfig();
rootContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext();
rootContext.setConfigLocation("abc-configuration.xml");
rootContext.refresh();
```

In spring configuration i have context property place holder as follows which i want to from code.

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:lnRuntime.properties"/>
```

i am using place holders in spring context and java file using spring EL as follows

```
<bean id="dataSource" 
class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.SingleConnectionDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbcx.JtdsDataSource"/>
        <property name="url" value="${dataSource.url}"/>
    </bean>
```

and in java i am accesing as follows

```
private @Value("${dz.host}") String dzHost;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found answer

```
@Bean
public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer properties(){
  PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer pspc =
   new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
  Resource[] resources = new ClassPathResource[ ]
   { new ClassPathResource( "foo.properties" ) };
  pspc.setLocations( resources );
  //pspc.setIgnoreUnresolvablePlaceholders( true );
  return pspc;
}
```

Resoruces http://www.baeldung.com/2012/02/06/properties-with-spring/#byhandnew